# can I empty a remote git repository?

Tags: git

I created new **remote git repository** and already pushed something in there - first test push and then real code push from local. I want to **start from scratch** so I can creat few branches (master = ready to release code, test branch and branches for developers) and give them different permissions per user.

Can I **empty the existing remote repository** somehow? It's a remote git repository that sits on linux and developer and I run windows box.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. By "pushed something in there" do you mean "pushed to a public remote" i.e. published? If so, then Steven Xu's answer is reasonable (though you should also be careful to delete any tracked hidden files), and I question how this is any better than simply starting completely over. Other devs won't have to rebase, but they'll get merge conflicts with *everything*. I'm confused about your end goal, too - you're asking about creating branches and giving them to developers...if you clarify what exactly you mean, I can probably give you a more helpful answer.

Comment: @Jefromi: I am happy to start completely over (in that case I want to keep the same repository name) or empty the existing remote repository. Which ever is easier .... (I updated my question)

Comment: As long as you have filesystem access, you might as well just wipe the directory and recreate the repo. It's clean, and it won't affect other devs a whole ton more than a complete rewrite - either way, they'll have to be aware of it.

Comment: looks like the easiest way :-) So I delete the .git directory and that's it.

Comment: @Jefromi: could you make an answer from your 'wiping comment' ? I will accept it as an answer then. I did that and I am happy now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the repo gone, just take it away! Delete the whole containing directory, and recreate it as you see fit.

Yes, you could also make a new repo just on your end, and force push to the remote, and remotely delete all the refs, and then make sure `git gc` gets run on it... but that takes time and effort. Just wipe it out.

Comment: worked nicely in my case. I might need the stuff from other question in the future too ....

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it is very useful, but you can restart the master branch (forgetting all history) by

```
rm .git/index .git/refs/heads/master
echo "Hello!" > README
git add README
git commit -m "Exterminate! Exterminate!"
```

and push to your remote repository.  Usually I would just start over with an empty repository, add your remote repository and push from there.

Some explanation:  The first line deletes the index (so your next commit won't contain any files) and the current pointer to the tip of the master branch (so your next commit won't be committed on top of any previous commit).  In the second and third line, we add some content to our new repository and commit that content in the fourth line.