# How can I remove everything from a remote Git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

#### How can I completely "start over" in-place?

How can I totally wipe out everything in a Git remote repository? I am the only client currently and before I can let it go public I have to wipe out all of the previous commits.

#### Not a duplicate because...

This question is about how to remove history, including the original base commit, without deleting the existing repository. My repository is on SourceForge, and the only way to do that is to destroy the whole project, which requires you to submit a Project Removal Request, which they don't always grant (especially in my case, where my project is younger than 90 days, so they won't grant it).

Comment: @EricSauer Just wipe it out.  I don't want to delete the actual repo, just its contents.

Comment: This might help, I'm still looking though.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120502/can-i-empty-a-remote-git-repository

Comment: Can you wipe out the repo and create a new one?

Comment: @KeithThompson I can't :(  My repository is on SourceForge, and the only way todo that is to destroy the whole project, which requires you to submit a Project Removal Request, which they don't always grant (especially in my case, where my project is younger than 90 days, they won't grant it).  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote name is `origin` and you have force-push rights on the remote repository, this will delete **every branch** and **every tag** in the remote repository:

```
REMOTE=origin

for i in .git/refs/$REMOTE/origin/*
do
    git push $REMOTE :"`basename "$i"`"
done

for i in `git tag`
do
    git push $REMOTE :refs/tags/$i
done
```

This is a destructive operation, so make sure that you *really* want to do this first.

Comment: He wants to wipe the commit history -- not just branches.

Comment: This is as close as you can come to wiping commits if you don't have direct access to the server (consider, for example, a GitHub repository).  After this operation, the commits will be orphaned (won't be reachable) in the remote repository and *will not be visible* to any clients.  The actual commit objects will be cleaned up at a later date when a `git gc` happens on the server.  This is similar to how a `DELETE` SQL command doesn't usually remove data from disk, but marks records deleted and a later garbage-collection process will come along and reclaim the space.

Comment: @cdhowie
`fatal: Invalid refspec ':*'`
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: @KevinOrr Then there is no `origin` remote, or the `origin` remote does not have any branches.  Try `git fetch origin` first.

Comment: @cdhowie
`$ git fetch origin`
`Password:`
`warning: no common commits`
`remote: Counting objects: 8, done.`
`remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.`
`remote: Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)`
`Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.`
`From ssh://git.code.sf.net/p/hangman4pygame/code`
` * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master`

`$ for i in .git/refs/$REMOTE/origin/*; do     git push $REMOTE :"`basename "$i"`"; done`
`Password:`
`fatal: Invalid refspec ':*'`
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: How do you escape a backtick?

Comment: You can surround the whole thing in three backticks.

Comment: @KevinOrr Try `export REMOTE=origin` first, then the rest of the script.  It looks like `REMOTE` is not set to anything.

Answer (score 3):

#### Push a (Mostly) Empty Branch

You have to have at least one commit on a branch in order to push it to a remote repository. If you have no heads at all, git won't have anything to send to *origin*. You can resolve this by making an empty branch with an empty commit. For example:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/empty_branch
rm .git/index
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initialize empty branch.'
git branch -M empty_branch master
git push --force origin
```

When you're done, both your current master and origin/master will contain exactly one file-free commit. The underlying objects in the repositories will eventually be reaped when git performs garbage collection.

#### Delete All Tags

If you want to delete all local and remote tags, you can push a set of empty references to the remote before deleting the tags locally. For example:

```
# Delete all tags present on the local host from the remote
# host in one push operation.
git for-each-ref --format=':%(refname)' --shell refs/tags |
    xargs git push origin

# Delete all local tags.
git tag -d $(git tag)
```

Comment: Let me suggest changing this answer to just delete all branches. This does not impose the constraint that the new history will have to be based on a specific initial commit.

Answer (score 1):

ssh to the server and do a `rm -rf .git` within the project directory. If you want to then put it under git again, run a `git init`.

Comment: The OP can't do that. In a comment posted after this answer, he says the repository is on SourceForge, and he can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Use git push command to delete branch

$git push origin :remotebranch_name

this will delete remote branch completely

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do that :

1. Create an empty git repository.

   `git init`
2. Make a dummy commit :

   `touch README.md
    git add README.md
    git commit -m "first commit"`
3. Reference the repo you want to overwrite :

   `git remote add origin REMOTE_URL`
4. Overwrite remote git

   `git push --force origin`
5. Remove existing remote tag (one by one)

   `git push --delete origin TAG_NAME`